# obtener el numero mas repetido y devolverlo

Tags: javascript, funciones, números-enteros

estoy queriendo hacer este ejercicio. Pero no se como obtener un entero mas repetido y devolverlo

```
function masFrecuente(array) {
// La funcion llamada 'masFrecuente' recibe como argumento un array de numeros enteros
// y debe devolver el número entero que mas veces aparece (el más frecuente).
// ej:
// masFrecuente([1,1,2,3,4]) => 1
// masFrecuente([3,2,3,2,3,3]) => 3
// Nota: Los numeros pueden NO estar ordenados
```

Comment: Buff la verdad es que tu profe los pone difíciles eh, pero en Stack overflow no somos de resolver ejercicios, sino de resolver problemas con los que te has encontrado intentando resolverlo, muestra lo que has intentado y entonces se te podrá ayudar. De paso puedes mirar el [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```js
(function() {
  array = [1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1];
  contadorInterno = 0;
  contadorMasRepetido = 0;
  variable = "";

  array.map(x => {
    contadorInterno = 0;
    array.map(y => {
      if (x === y) {
        contadorInterno++;
      }
    })

    if (contadorInterno > contadorMasRepetido) {
      contadorMasRepetido = contadorInterno;
      variable = x;
    }
  });
  console.log(`valor mas repetido:${variable}, numero de veces contada: ${contadorMasRepetido}`)
})();
```

Te explico lo que hice en el código:
1- Se declaran variables, un contador interno (contadorInterno), una variable que vaya guardando el numero que se ha repetido un mayor de veces durante cada iteracion(contadorMasRepetido) y otra variable que guarde el numero que es el que mas veces se ha repetido(variable).

2- Se recorre el array y adentro del mismo se recorre nuevamente, si no tienes claro la función map, hazte a la idea que lo que estas haciendo es un foreach dentro de otro foreach para así recorrer el arreglo y poder comparar uno a uno, cada numero del arreglo con todos los demás números adentro del mismo.

3- Se establece un condicional para que cada vez que el numero que escoja del recorrido externo o primer array.map sea igual a los del arreglo interior que es el segundo array.map vaya sumando 1 en el contador interno.

4- Se establece un condicional por fuera en el cual se guarda el resultado del contador interno y ese valor solo se reemplaza cuando el valor obtenido en las iteraciones realizadas, sea mayor al ultimo guardado, de esta manera se valida que el valor guardado sea en efecto el numero mas repetido.

Espero que quedara clara la explicación y que pueda ser de ayuda para ti y otras personas que en su momento requieran la información.

Comment: _Hay que enseñar a pescar, no a dar el pescado_ :) Por favor, lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.